# how to create a search box for an express app

Tags: mongodb, express

I wants to create a search box which takes the input and search all the content related to input string from my own website and displays the list of all the contents as a link to that particular content.
(similar like udemy)
i am stuck due to this, Can you please give me some idea how to build this
(i am using mongoDB database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by searching the input value from your database, you can search it using the title or description. If that word is present in the title or description then you can display all the objects with that title or description on your result page.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and use EJS which is a simple templating language that lets you generate HTML markup with plain JavaScript.
[https://ejs.co/#install][1]

- Then you can require it in your app.js file by taking help of the doc link above.
- Create a another folder called views in your project folder in the same hierarchical level as you app.js.
- Inside the views folder you can create two ejs files

Comment: Thanks for the Help but actually i need an idea for backend like how to get all results which relate the input string